# Zooming with ginput() active in Matlab

Tags: matlab, scroll, keyboard, zooming, ginput

Is there a way to zoom into an image with ginput() active? I have done some research an have found nothing.

I have thought about somehow doing:

Ctrl-Left Click to zoom in
Ctrl - Right Click to zoom out

I am currently using Left Click to select points and Right click to exit ginput().

Does anyone know how this can be done. I included my conde below. Please tell me if I can do something different so i can use the zoom feature.

The image is in axes.

```
function digitize_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to digitize (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
ng=0;
nXY = [];
n=0;
      [writefname, writepname] = uiputfile('*.txt','Save data as');
      writepfname = fullfile(writepname, writefname);
      fid = fopen(writepfname,'wt');


    while 1
      [x,y, buttonNumber] = ginput(1);
      if buttonNumber == 1, 
           line(x,y,'Marker','.','Color','r','MarkerSize',12)
           sn = num2str(n + 1);
           text(x,y, sn)

           %xpt(n) = x;
           %ypt(n) = y;
           n = n+1;
           disp(sprintf(' %4d         %f      %f',n, x, y))
           ng = ng+1;
           nXY(ng,:) = [n x y];

           fprintf(fid,'%g,%g,%g\n',n, x, y');


     else
           query = questdlg('STOP digitizing and QUIT ?', ...
                'DIGITIZE: confirmation', ...
                'YES', 'NO', 'NO');
           drawnow
           switch upper(query),
            case 'YES',
             disp(sprintf('\n'))
             break;
             case 'No',

           end % switch query

      end
    end
      fclose(fid);
```

Comment: You'll need to write your own [Button Down Callback Function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/button-down-callback-function.html) so you can avoid using `ginput`.

Comment: @excaza When I load the image it won't output any coordinates. When there is no image, it outputs coordinates.

Comment: [Image objects](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/image-properties.html) have their own button down callback.